# Finding P(S1 = 1 | D1=1, D2=1) (Bayes Networks)

Tags: bayesian-network

I'm scratching my head over something that is probably simple Probabilities, but I guess I can't see it.
Essentially, I have the following table:

```
 ------ ------ ------ ------
|  D1  |  D2  | S1=1 | S1=0 |
 ------ ------ ------ ------
|  0   |  0   |  0   |  1   |
 ------ ------ ------ ------
|  0   |  1   |  0.8 |  0.2 |
 ------ ------ ------ ------
|  1   |  0   | 0.75 | 0.25 |
 ------ ------ ------ ------
|  1   |  1   |  ?   |  ?   |
 ------ ------ ------ ------
```

Where, for example, the 0.8 in line 3 column 3 is the value for P(S1 = 1 | D2=1).
I'm having trouble finding The ones marked with ?, namely P(S1=1 | D1=1, D2=1) (the other one is trivially 1-P(S1=1 | D1=1, D2=1)). Any help?

Thank you for your time in advance. I'll provide more details if necessary!

Comment: I don't think it's possible to deduce those values based only on the other figures in the table. The effect that $D_1=1\; D_2=1$ has on $S_1$ could be anything.

Comment: We do know P(S1 | D1) and P(S1 | D2). I did forget to mention that P(D1) = 0.01 and P(D2) = 0.02. Does that change anything? It really is a head scratcher for me, but this was part of my solution for an AI test I had. I couldn't get past that and it always bugged me.

Comment: _Do_ you know $P(S_1\mid D_1)$?? Line 3 Col 3 says $P(S_1=1\mid D_1=0\cap D_2=1)=0.8$. Anyway, I still think you need more info to answer the question. Such as $P(S_1=1)$. Is that given? I guess also that $D_1,D_2$ are independent.